# Make a GameObject stick to another GameObjects border in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm using Unity3D with MRTK for Hololens 2 development.

As you can see in the picture I gat a `Square`-Gameobject and a `AppBar`-Gameobject. The `Square` hast MRTK `BoundsControl` attached to it which make it transformable. The user can change the size and rotation of the `Square` with the handles.

On every change the user does the `AppBar` should stick to the left border of the `Square`.

The `Object`-Gameobject has a scale of: X: 1, Y: 1, Z: 1.
The `Square`-Gameobject has a scale of: X: 0.15, y: 0.15, Z: 0.009.

When I scale the `Square` with the handles only the scale of the `Object` changes the scale of the `Square` is staying the same all the time.

I already tried this code but it doesn't work properly:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AppBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject appBar;
    public GameObject MaterialObject;
    public void MoveAppBar()
    {

        var distance = MaterialObject.transform.localScale.x + MaterialObject.transform.GetChild(0).localScale.x - 1;
        appBar.transform.position = new Vector3(-distance - 0.032f, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an empty object to the edge of the object that gets scale up/down. It needs to be on the edge so that when the main object gets modified, it will remain on the border.

Add this code to a script on the UI:

```
public Transform tr;
public float offset;
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = tr.position;
    pos.x += offset;
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Drag the empty object to the tr slot and give a value to offset to indicate how far from that empty object you want the UI to remain.

Now you should be able to scale the main object and the UI will stick to that same distance from the edge without getting further or inside the main object.

A better approach would be to listen to the main object modification via event/listener so you don't run the update even when nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. After implementing your solution I face another problem. When I rotate the game object around its own axis, the menu doesn't move with the edge it should be attached to. This causes the menu to move inside the GameObject when I rotate the GameObejct. Do you have a solution?